Can I upload a pdf document and then create an html template from the uploaded pdf using Angular
I am uploading a UI template which is in pdf format. I want that file to be uploaded and then after reading the file want the exact template in HTML format for further use. Is it possible to achieve this feature in angular. Thanks in advance for any leads.

        <div>
          <h2>Upload PDF</h2>
          <input type="file" (change)="onFileSelected($event)" accept="application/pdf" />
        </div>
<div id="output">
  <!-- Extracted HTML content will be displayed here -->
</div>
    /******************************************************************/
        import { Component } from '@angular/core';
        import { PDFDocument } from 'pdf-lib';
        
        @Component({
          selector: 'app-upload-pdf',
          templateUrl: './upload-pdf.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./upload-pdf.component.css']
        })
        export class UploadPdfComponent {
        
          async onFileSelected(event: Event) {
            const input = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
            if (input.files && input.files.length > 0) {
              const file = input.files[0];
              const fileReader = new FileReader();
              fileReader.onload = async () => {
                const arrayBuffer = fileReader.result as ArrayBuffer;
                const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(arrayBuffer);
                
                // For simplicity, we'll extract text from the first page only
                const firstPage = pdfDoc.getPage(0);
                const { text } = await firstPage.getTextContent();
                
                // Convert text content to HTML (this is a simple example, you may need to style it appropriately)
                const htmlContent = text.items.map(item => `<p>${item.str}</p>`).join('');
                
                // Insert the HTML content into a div (you can also store it for further use)
                const outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
                if (outputDiv) {
                  outputDiv.innerHTML = htmlContent;
                }
              };
              fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
            }
          }
        }


Hi Thanks for the share. Property 'getTextContent' does not exist on type 'PDFPage' is the error I am getting
